# File permissions not working

Tags: permissions, chmod

A file on my CentOS does not have write permission and can not be edited using vim. But using echo it can be written, why?

```
[root@srv chap2]# cat raj.txt 

Hello World

[root@srv chap2]# ls -l raj.txt 

---------- 1 root root 12 Sep 22 17:37 raj.txt

[root@srv chap2]# echo "Hello World Again" >> raj.txt 

[root@srv chap2]# cat raj.txt 

Hello World
Hello World Again

[root@srv chap2]# ls -l raj.txt 

---------- 1 root root 30 Sep 22 17:38 raj.txt
```

Comment: You are running as root. Permissions don't really apply to root. Don't use your Unix as root.

Comment: What is the output of `lsattr raj.txt`? If it includes the `a` flag, the file is set "append-only", so you can add to it using `>>` but any modification of existing content will be prohibited.

Comment: @Kusalananda still, there's something interesting here. The question boils down to "why can shell redirection edit the file while a text editor cannot?". Interestingly, while `emacs` and `vi` won't write to it, `nano` will. I suspect it has something to do with [how `emacs` and `vi` recreate the original file, while `nano` just edits it in place.](https://askubuntu.com/a/444079/85695)

Comment: I don't buy yoir claim that that file cannot be edited in vim. It's just that you'll have to use `:x!`, `:w!` or `:wq!` with the bangs (`!`) when writing out the file.

Comment: @pizdelect whoops, my bad, you're right. `w!` does indeed work. Emacs still doesn't let me edit though. And `vi` does warn that it's read only. `nano` just ignores the permissions entirely.

Comment: Simple editors just do what the user asks. More complex ones like `vim` (which is what your `vi` probably is) and `emacs` will look at the file permissions and switch on a special mode for read-only files.With `vi` you can override it by adding `!` to the write commands, with `emacs` you would need `M-x toggle-read-only` or `M-x read-only-mode` depending on Emacs version.

Comment: @telcoM so, basically, they're just sophisticated enough to make even root jump through some hoops before writing, but that was a choice by their devs and doesn't imply that root ever needs to respect permissions?

Comment: @terdon I believe that's basically it. An editor could examine the permissions of the file and warn the user that the file is not writable, even when that user is root. The shell doesn't implement that "safety check" (and shouldn't do).

Answer (score 0):

`lsatter` will show whether the append-only attribute is enabled on your file:

```
lsattr filename
```

If it's enabled, the output will look like this:

```
-----a--------e--- filename
```

meaning that you can only append to the file.